# Does 1-1/4 mean a number or a range?

Tags: meaning

This [tutorial](https://youtu.be/VpzPLIXFkHU?t=60) pronounces 1-1/4 as

> one and a quarter

Does mean a number (1.25) or a range (from 1 to 1.25)?

Comment: I'm sure whoever made that tutorial just stuck at the tricky requirement to look up Alt-key codes to display 1¼

Comment: Perhaps “1-1/4” is acceptable amongst builders but it is not at all a widely accepted way to write “one and a quarter”.  Experts of all sorts develop their own habits and terminologies that may be “correct” within their group but “incorrect” elsewhere. For example, in Australia builders pronounce “mills” as the shortened form of “millimetres” (mm) but everyone else pronounces “mills” when they read the shortened form of “millilitres” (mls).